# Who is the "Narayana" valmiki is comparing Kumbhakarna to?

Tags: kumbhakarna

http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga65/yuddha_65_frame.htm

> स काञ्चनं भारसहं निवातं |
> विद्युत्प्रभम् दीप्तमिवात्मभासा |
> आबध्यमानः कवचम् रराज |
> सन्ध्याभ्रसम्वीत इवाद्रिराजः || ६-६५-३०

> Secured with a golden armour, carrying a great load, impenetrable by weapons and as if blazing with its own splendour with flashing like lightning, Kumbhakarna shone as a king of Mountains, enveloped by clouds at sunset.

> सर्वाभरणनद्धाङ्गः शूलपाणिः स राक्षसः |
> त्रिविक्रमकृतोत्साहो **नारायण** इवाबभौ || ६-६५-३१

> Adorned with all ornaments to all his limbs and with a spike in his hand, that demon shone like Narayana, the all-embracing Lord, enthusiastic to take the three long strides (which were meant to cover the entire universe).

"Shulapani" doesn't usually signify Vishnu.  Is the comparison to the giant form of Vamana who took the three giant strides?

**NOTE: SITE TAGGING POLICIES PREVENT THE TAG "Narayana" FOR THIS QUESTION**

Answer (score 3):

Here, there is simply a statement that Kumbakaran, with his ornaments and a spike in his hand, seems to be as glorious and powerful as the all-powerful god Narayana. It does not mean that Kumbakaran seems like Narayan as Narayan carries a spike at hand. This is trying to tell us it is Kumbhakarna who takes a spike as the weapon of his choice.

*Side Note: While of course it is also true that Narayan in his thousand hands probably carries a spear, it is not what's being referred to in this case. Just a FYI so you don't think Narayan never has a spike.*

**स काञ्चनं भारसहं निवातं |
विद्युत्प्रभम् दीप्तमिवात्मभासा |
आबध्यमानः कवचम् रराज |
सन्ध्याभ्रसम्वीत इवाद्रिराजः || ६-६५-३०**

***"Secured with a golden armour, carrying a great load, impenetrable by weapons and as if blazing with its own splendour with flashing like lightning, Kumbhakarna shone as a king of Mountains, enveloped by clouds at sunset."***

Here Kumbhakarana is said to be like the king of mountains due to his armour and weapons, it does not mean that Kumbhakarna seems so because the mountain also has armour and weapons. It is a sort of an metaphor in order to vividly represent the idea of how Kumbhakarna might have looked and what he is wearing/taking to war.

And for the what incarnation the 3 steps refers to then that is the Vamana incarnation, again it does not mean Kumbhakarna is like Vamana because of what he is wearing or holding but simply stating he seems that powerful and mightily to be able to take conquer everything in 3 steps. Also don't get confused because of the name 'Narayana' as the names of the god are used interchangeably for his incarnations as they are one and the same with no difference. If you have ever read the geeta Arjun calls Krishna names as 'Keshava'.

Hopefully I was able to answer your questions. If I made any mistakes in my interpretation or confused you then I sincerely apologize.